# Upgrade Rails 3.1 to 3.2: my vendor/engine/<engine>/config/initializers dont run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have debug output in my engines and I see that the `vendor/engines/<engine>/lib/<engine>.rb` is run and its corresponding `vendor/engines/<engine>/lib/<engine>/engine.rb` is as well.

I followed this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html

Searched around. Cannot resolve this issue. Any ideas?

Im using ruby 2.0.0p645 and rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove this line from `config/application.rb` (in order for my rais 3.1 code to work in rails 3.2):

```
    #config.railties_order = [DfcBase::Engine, :main_app, DfcAuth::Engine, DfcDash::Engine, DfcLog::Engine, :all]
```